# About restricting variables in an integrand, and also changing the look of an integrands.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

So, in the last step of, many, integrands, Wolfram chooses to restrict the $x$-values, even if I didn't specify which values $x$ can take on.

Take for example:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x(x^2-1)^{3/2}} = -\cot(\sec^{-1}(x))-\sec^{-1}(x)+C$$

Checking with Wolfram gives a different option, an option that, in accordance to their step-by-step solver comes from the fact that they restrict the $x$-values. I'm not sure *how* they restrict it, but it [apparently becomes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F%28x%28x%5E2-1%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29): 
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right) - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

*Why do they restrict $x$?* *Is this the usual thing to do?* And if so, **why?**

I also want to ask **how** to change the expression from LHS to RHS by restricting the $x$-values. $$-\cot(\sec^{-1}(x))-\sec^{-1}(x) = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right) - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Comment: Since the sign of $x^2 - 1$ can change along the real axis, it's germane to symbolic integration routines to restrict $x$ to subintervals where it does not change sign, in order to form expressions valid in those restricted intervals.

Comment: Oh, I see. And a follow up question, how do I get from the first expression ($-\cot(\sec^{-1}(x))-\sec^{-1}(x)$) RHS to Wolfram's answer (2nd expression)? (If anyone cares to explain)

Comment: Actually, why not edit your Question (no Answers so far) to raise that issue?

Answer (score 1):

- If you are surprised to see that the same indefinite integral $\big($anti-derivative$\big)$ can be expressed in two or more *apparently* different ways, see for example [Gudermannian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function).
- To show that the two functions are indeed identical, use $x=\sec t$, and $\sec^2t-1=\tan^2t$.